# Distributive sublattices of atomistic ortholattices

Tags: lattice-theory, boolean-algebras

Let $L$ be an atomistic ortholattice (i.e. every element can be written as a join of atoms) with top and bottom elements 0 and 1, and let $M$ be a distributive atomic  sub-ortholattice of $L$.

Is $M$ generated by its atoms, in the sense that every element in $M$ can be written as a join of the atoms in $M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $L$ be the power set of ${\bf N}$ ordered by inclusion. It is an atomic Boolean algebra. Let a subset of ${\bf N}$ belong to $M$ if its characteristic function is periodic. Then $M$ is a nonatomic Boolean subalgebra of $L$.

Comment: what if I impose the additional condition that $M$ is atomic? 

Comment: Not sure what you mean ... to me, "atomic" means that every element is a join of atoms.

Comment: Also, when you edit a question to add conditions you should include a comment that you've done so.

Comment: Yes, good idea about the comment. I understand atomic to mean that $M$ has atoms, while atomistic means that every element is a join of atoms.

Comment: Having one atom is not going to help you, you can modify the example to take all subsets of $\mathbb N$ whose characteristic function is periodic on $\mathbb N-\{0\}$. This algebra has an atom, namely $\{0\}$, but only two of its elements are joins of atoms. (The general form of Nik’s answer is that *every* Boolean algebra is a subalgebra of a powerset algebra, by the way.)

Comment: As for edit summaries, they are shown in the revision history of the post, which you can retrieve by clicking on the “edited XXXX ago” link below the post. (The link is not shown if there is only the initial revision; in that case you can type the URL manually, it has the form http://mathoverflow.net/revisions/XXXX/list where XXXX is the numerical id of the post.)